# How to get largest value in multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
var max = 0;
var newArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
        max = Math.max(max, arr[i][j]);
    }
    newArr.push(max);
 }
 return newArr;
}
```

Here is my code. It works for me but I want to know is there any other sort way to do this?

Comment: You can ask people to review your code at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(item){
    return Math.max.apply(null, item);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Idea, `Math.max` takes `n` arguments and gives you the max value. Using `.apply` you can pass parameters as array. Combining both will give you max value in an array.

#### Apply

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [10, 20, 200, 31],
  [21, 3, 444, 133],
  [0, 0, 90, 1]
];
var max_arr = data.map(function(a) {
  return Math.max.apply(this, a);
});
console.log(max_arr)
```

#### Sort + slice + pop

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [10, 20, 200, 31],
  [21, 3, 444, 133],
  [0, 0, 90, 1]
];

var max_arr = data.map(function(a) {
  return a.sort().slice(-1).pop()
});

console.log(max_arr)
```

Comment: Yes, it works but it only returns largest number. I want to return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array.

Comment: @KaanKaraca I have updated the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Now it's better.

Comment: @KaanKaraca I have added an alternate approach for `.apply`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) as:

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [10, 20, 200, 31],
  [21, 3, 444, 133],
  [0, 0, 90, 1]
];
const max = Math.max(...data.map(inner => Math.max(...inner)));
console.log(max);
```